# Autoupdate package.json version with Dependabot

Tags: npm, package.json, dependabot, dependabot-script

So when Dependabot runs and create a PR with a library update it's updates the library version in the package.json and package-lock.json, but is there any config that I could be missing, that in every PR of the dependabot update the package.json version too, for example:

```
  {
  "name": "my-projetc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Some description",
  "private": true,
  "author": "My",
  "license": "MIT",
  ...
  dependencies: {
   ...
  }
  devDependencies: {
   ...
  }
```

The current version is **version: 0.0.1**

After run dependabot and create the corresponding PR for some library update, is there a way to increase the number of the package.json (with semver), like this:

```
      {
      "name": "my-projetc",
      "version": "0.0.2",
      "description": "Some description",
      "private": true,
      "author": "My",
      "license": "MIT",
      ...
      dependencies: {
       ...
      }
      devDependencies: {
       ...
      }
```

After the update the version should be: **version: 0.0.2**

According to the [documentation](https://dependabot.com/docs/config-file/#automerged_updates) there are existing options for

```
* automerged_updates and
* version_requirement_updates
```

But both options are for updating the versions of the **libraries** used inside the dependencies or **devDependencies**.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's something dependabot worries about. You can probably do that in your CI, using the `npm version` command.